# Importing something without evaluating the dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following file:

```
/** myFile.ts **/

import something from 'something';
/** ... other imports here ... **/

export enum statuses = {
  100 = "ok"
  200 = "false"
};

export default class Model {
   ....
}
```

This is a dummy ORM model, which is used on the back-end. Now, what I would like to achieve, is to use part of it (specifically the `enum` from it) on the front-end also (which has a completely separate code base, with it's own `node_modules` and dependencies) but if I try to import the `enum` from this file, the `something` plugin dependencies is also being evaluated and imported, and my code fails, as that dependency is not part of the front-end codes dependencies.

Is there any way to perform an import on a javascript file, WITHOUT evaluating the dependencies and other part of the code? (with the known risk, that it may fail, if I try to import something that would need those dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, the answer is "no," and I'm 99% sure that's true for when TypeScript is handling the imports as well.

But it's easy to fix: Put the `enum` in its own module:

`statuses.ts`:

```typescript
export enum statuses = {
  100 = "ok"
  200 = "false"
};
```

The other project can import from that, rather than from `myFile.ts`.

If you want, you make it so you don't have to update the code that *does* use `myFile.ts` to use that separate module, by re-exporting it in `myFile.ts`:

```typescript
export { statuses } from "./path/to/statuses.js";
```

Or if you need to use `statuses` in `myFile.ts` (which you can't with the above):

```typescript
import { statuses } from "./path/to/statuses.js";
export { statuses };
```

Either way, code that was doing `import Modal, { statuses } from "./myFile.js"` keeps working.

Comment: that is what I was hoping to circumvent, using a separate file fora variable:)